# How to fix "RuntimeError : dictionary changed size during iteration" ,while editing some of graph data

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, graph-theory

Objectif : I have a graph,for each node having degree two, i would like to remove that node and add an edge between the neighbors of that node (weight = a*b/a+b , with a and b are weights of the adjacent edges to the node in question).I want to do those operations every time the graph changes,to eventually have a graph without any node with dgree 2 . here is my code attached. PS:I'm very new to python(3.4.0),NetworkX 2.2
(Any other suggestion to give similar result is appreciated)

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G=nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,6),(6,7)])



for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True):
    d['weight'] = 1



def fun(G) : 
    L= G.degree() # L=list of all nodes of a random graph G ,and their nodes [(node, degree),(node,degree)...]
    for x in L : 
        if x[1] == 2 : #if a certain node in L has a degree 2 
            adja=G.edges(x[0],data=True) #adjacent edges to the node of degree 2 
            weights = [d['weight'] for u,v,weight in adja] #weights=list of weights of the adjacent edges to the node x[0](the one having degree 2)

            numerator=weights[0]*weights[1]
            denominator=sum(weights)
            var=numerator/denominator #var is the weight i would like to assign to my new edge created,it is computed like : a*b /(a+b) with a and b are weights of the adjacent edges to the node in question

            tmp=list(G.neighbors(x[0])) #tmp = list of neighbors of the node to remove(neighbors in term of nodes)
            G.remove_node(x[0]) #remove the node of degree 2
            G.add_edge(tmp[0],tmp[1],weight=var) #add an edge between the neighbors of the node of degree 2 

nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)
plt.show()

print(fun(G))
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner ,thank you for the quick response , I'm new to python , i don't know how to" store the key to modify in a list, iterate to end, then modify the dict" in my case

Comment: here I attached the complete code,with explainations for each instruction

Comment: You can fix the immediate error by using a copy of L to iterate over:  `for x in L[:] :` -but I think L does not look like you think - I am unfamiliar with `networkx` -I added it as tag and hope someone will come along :) sorry.

Comment: I really appreciate your help , Thank you

Comment: @PatrickArtner i would like to say that your hint helped me solve the problem , and now it works ,THANK YOU ALOT. here is what I added to the previous code(for other users who may face the same problem) : L= list(L1)
for x in L

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Runtime error with networkx : dictionary changed during iteration while running a neural gas script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321965/runtime-error-with-networkx-dictionary-changed-during-iteration-while-running)