# Runtime error with networkx : dictionary changed during iteration while running a neural gas script

Tags: python, neural-network, networkx

I am trying to run a neural gas network with an older script that doesn't work well with networkx 2 so I modified some things.
However I am getting the error : Dictionary changed size during iteration and I don't get how to fix this because networkx is not my speciality. Any help?

The code that is causing the problem right now:

```
def prune_connections(self, a_max):


    for u, v, attributes in self.network.edges(data=True):



        if attributes['age'] > a_max:



            self.network.remove_edge(u, v)



    for u in self.network.nodes():



        if self.network.degree(u) == 0:



            self.network.remove_node(u)
```

and the error I am getting :

```
    in __iter__

        for nbr, dd in nbrs.items():

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you're looping through the edges of the graph:

`for u, v, attributes in self.network.edges(data=True):`

But within that loop you modify the edges.  So `self.network.edges` (which is fundamentally a dictionary) is changing while you're iterating.  This isn't allowed by python.

A solution to this is to predefine

`edgelist = list(self.network.edges(data=True))`

then do

`for u, v, attributes in edgelist:`