# NetworkX: Filter Edges

Tags: networkx

My edgelist comes from the following dataframe:
[image]

My code is:

```
G_test = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(n1, 'Sentence0', 'Sentence1', edge_attr='CosineSimilarity', 
create_using=nx.Graph())
pos = nx.spring_layout(G_test)
nx.draw_networkx(
        G_test, 
        pos=pos,
        with_labels=False,
       )
```

My questions are:

1. I want those edges (cosine similarity) <0.5 to show a different color rather than black.
2. For the nodes, currently I hid the node labels since nodes are the sentences that are too long, I want to ask how I can use shorter labels?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through your edges and check whether your `edge_attr` ('CosineSimilarity') is above or below your threshold. You can then associate a color to the edge based on that.

See example below with a minimal dataset based on the one you provided:

```py
Sentence0 Sentence1 CosineSimilarity  
'a'        'b'      0.68
'a'        'c'      0.67
'a'        'd'      0.44
'a'        'e'      0.18
'a'        'f'      0.25
```

And the code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_fwf('dat.txt')
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Sentence0', 'Sentence1', edge_attr='CosineSimilarity', create_using=nx.Graph())

edge_color_list=[]
thresh=0.5
for e in G.edges(data=True): #Loop through edges
  if e[2]['CosineSimilarity']>=thresh: #check edge attribute value
    edge_color_list.append('tab:blue') #add color to list
  else:
    edge_color_list.append('tab:orange')

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos,with_labels=True,edge_color=edge_color_list)

#create legend
plt.plot([],[],color='tab:blue',label='>='+str(thresh))
plt.plot([],[],color='tab:orange',label='<'+str(thresh))
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

And the output gives:

[image]

When it comes to node labels, my suggestion would to use a shorter version of the different sentences (first word, first letters of each word etc.).

#### EDIT:

To remove the edges with a 'CosineSimilarity' below 0.5, you first need to create a separate edge list, loop over this list and remove the edges from the graph.

See code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_fwf('dat.txt')
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Sentence0', 'Sentence1', edge_attr='CosineSimilarity', create_using=nx.Graph())

edge_color_list=[]
thresh=0.5
edges=list(G.edges(data=True))
for e in edges: 
  if e[2]['CosineSimilarity']>=thresh: 
    edge_color_list.append('tab:blue') 
  else:
    G.remove_edge(*e[:2]) 
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos,with_labels=True,edge_color=edge_color_list)

plt.plot([],[],color='tab:blue',label='>='+str(thresh))
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: Hi jylls, I got one more question. I was trying to remove the edges that cosine similarity is <0.5, I used the following code but getting errors: thresh=0.5
for e in G_test.edges(data=True): #Loop through edges
  if e[2]['CosineSimilarity']>=thresh: #check edge attribute value
    edge_color_list.append('tab:blue') #add color to list
  else:
    G_test.remove_edge_from(G_test.edges)

Comment: it's not possible to directly remove edges while looping through them (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321965/runtime-error-with-networkx-dictionary-changed-during-iteration-while-running)). Instead, you need first to create a list of all the edges: `edges=list(G.edges(data=True))` and then loop through that list and remove the edges below the threshold:
  

`for e in edges: 
  if e[2]['CosineSimilarity']>=thresh: 
    edge_color_list.append('tab:blue') 
  else:
    G.remove_edge(*e[:2]) `

Comment: Hi jylls, I appreciate your help and time! I used the code, but getting this error "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration". thresh=0.5
for e in G_test.edges(data=True): #Loop through edges
  if e[2]['CosineSimilarity']>=thresh: #check edge attribute value
    edge_color_list.append('tab:blue') #add color to list
  else:
    G_test.remove_edge(*e[:2])

Comment: I will edit my answer so you can see more what I meant

Comment: Thank you so much, jylls! I tried the edits, works perfectly!

Comment: Just want to say "thank you" again for being so helpful, jylls!